# how to align some 3 buttons on the right side of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div and want to place some buttons eg; 3 buttons to the right side of the div. Can anyone help how to achieve this?

I am using Primeng with Angular2

```
<div class="ui-g-12" style="border:solid 1px red;">
  <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-info" label="BUTTON1"></button>
  <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-danger" label="BUTTON2"></button>
</div>
```

Thanks

Here is my current output. I need the button to be placed on the right side
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<div class="ui-g-12" style="border:solid 1px red; text-align:right">
  <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-info" label="BUTTON1"></button>
  <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-danger" label="BUTTON2"></button>
</div>
```

There is nothing link to Angular2

You just need to add css property `text-align: right`

For more get in touch here

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: `float: right;` to the parent container totally not needed. It floats the div to right, not buttons inside.

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: right;` to the parent of your buttons:

```html
<div class="ui-g-12" style="text-align: right; border:solid 1px red;">
  <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-info" label="BUTTON1"></button>
  <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-danger" label="BUTTON2"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much